# How to split values from a CSV file in python using pandas or otherwise?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

For an assignment, I am given a CSV file with various bits of data about a bunch of movies. One of the columns of the CSV is titled 'Genre' which ostensibly gives the genre of the movie and we are also given the gross income of the movie. In the genres column, many of the movies have multiple genres attached to them such as 'Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama' etc. with each genre separated by the character `|` when there is more than one genre attached to a movie. I am asked to plot a bar graph that shows the gross total income of each movie by genre where my horizontal (or x-axis) is the genre and the vertical (or y-axis) is the dollar amount that each genre has supposedly brought in.

Thus far I have managed to extract just the genre and gross columns using pandas

```
#DataFrame is denoted by variable name movie_data


genre_and_gross = movie_data[['gross','genres']]
```

Where I am getting stuck here is that I cannot just simply use `pd.dF.groupBy.sum()` because I have multiple genres per cell in some cases and that wouldn't give me the data that I need. Is there a way to utilize the `split()` function perhaps to so that if a cell had a gross of 1 million dollars and was given the genres action and comedy, I would be able to add 1 million dollars to both the values of genre and comedy when I did my bar graph?

For reference, this is an example of a line of the CSV File:

```
Color,James Cameron,723,178,0,855,Joel David Moore,1000,760505847,Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi,CCH Pounder,Avatar ,886204,4834,Wes Studi,0,avatar|future|marine|native|paraplegic,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,3054,English,USA,PG-13,237000000,2009,936,7.9,1.78,33000
```

Comment: If a movie has multiple genres, should the movie be assigned to multiple genres (thus duplicating the gross income), or should it be assigned to one genre (which keeps the whole dataset gross income constant)?

Comment: I asked this same question of my professor and he said to add the income to both genres even though obviously this will lead to more income being shown in the graph than was actually brought in in the graphical representation

Comment: @Banani720 Could you provide a sample line of data for one movie?

Comment: Yes I stepped out to take my brother to soccer practice but should be back in ~1hr

Comment: Please include data as text in the post itself, not as an image. Can you also share **all** relevant code and data? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you said this is an assignment, here is a way this could be achieved using a similar data set, once you understand you should be able to apply it to your own dataset.

You are spot on with the assumption split can be utilized to achieve the result.

```
movie = [['StackOverflow', ['1,000,000', 'Action|Comedy|Drama']]]
result = []

for item in movie:
    value = []
    genres = item[1][1].split('|')
    for v in genres:
        value.append((v, item[1][0]))
    result.append([item[0], value])

print(result)
#[[MovieName, [(Genre, Gross)]], [MovieName, [(Genre, Gross)]]]
>>>[['StackOverflow', [('Action', '1,000,000'), ('Comedy', '1,000,000'), ('Drama', '1,000,000')]]]
```

Comment: I tried to apply this method and I am getting an error where you have `genres = item[1][1].split("|")` is giving me an index out of range error

Comment: @Banani720 this is where migrating it to your own dataset will change how you have to split it. Look at the variable I set n the first line, that item[1] = '1,000,000' item[1][1] = 'Action|Comedy|Drama'

Comment: So if I am translating this into my data set, where you have `Stack Overflow` this is the movie name. In my case, the genre is in column 9 so it would be `item[1][9]`?

Comment: Yes, correct. Just map your indexes to where they sit within your dataset